# How to determine that a form has finished opening in C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I'm having some problems with my form and the business class:

The form does not open until the business class has finished it's work. Every time I call Form1 in `Main()`, Form1 calls two methods:

`InitializeComponents();

 testConnection();`

`testConnection` calls the business class and sets the properties of the Form according to the properties of the business class. Like that:

`Pingger pingger = new Pingger();

 ipLabel.Text = pingger.getLocalIP();`

I do not do just these operations, I also do others like the result of a ping. However, Form1 takes a long time to open and when it's open Form1 shows the results. What do I have to do, create Form1, open it, and then after 3 seconds start to process the business class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder you want to show the form just before the connection is tested?

The idea could be using multi-threading like the Wonderbird suggestion, using some like this:

```
    InitializeComponent();
    new Thread(testConnection).Start();
```

Answer (score 3):

What you want is an event raised by your form control. To determine if there is such an event you simply Google the class (ie `Form`). On the msdn page every property, method and event is listed accompanied with what they do.

What you want is the `Shown` event. You can add an event to this and then handle whatever it is you want to do. See link below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll look at next time that I have a question.

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe to the [Shown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event for the form and call your `testConnection()` method from there.

```
InitializeComponents();
Shown += (s,e) => testConnection();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use multi-threading to "launch" the testConnection() method.  (but then you have the added complexity of making sure the results are in before you rely on them, thread safety, etc...)